# How to get a directory path with html5 <input> tag

Tags: javascript, html, file, directory

I want to get a directory's full path through html's `<input>` method, but when I try to use the `type="file" webkitdirectory multiple` tag, I just select all of the files in a directory to upload. How can I get the path a directory? And also, how can I get the path value in javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/15201071/13765033

Comment: @DavidWolf this is jquery, which I don't want to use.

Comment: Please check out all of the answers. This one for example is made using vanilla JavaScript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36311820/13765033